# Как сделать, чтобы через определенное время генерировалось рандомное число?

Tags: javascript

После загрузки страницы генерируется рамдомное число. Но мне нужно чтобы каждые 100ms оно менялось. Оно не меняется.

```js
$(function() {
  function myRandom(from, to) {
    var empty = [];
    return Math.floor((Math.random() * (to - from + 1)) + from);
  }

  var ramd1 = myRandom(100, 1200);

  function myRandom2(from, to) {
    return Math.floor((Math.random() * (to - from + 1)) + from);
  }

  var ramd2 = myRandom2(100, 1200);

  setInterval(myRandom, 100);
  setInterval(myRandom2, 100);

  document.write(ramd1 + "<br />" + ramd2);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых, [setInterval](http://javascript.ru/setinterval) не умеет обрабатывать возврат функции.
Во-вторых, то что вы уже вывели в HTML не поменяется без вашего участия.

Пример, исправления кода:

```js
$(function() {
  function myRandom(from, to) {
    return Math.floor((Math.random() * (to - from + 1)) + from);
  }

  function myRandom2(from, to) {
    return Math.floor((Math.random() * (to - from + 1)) + from);
  }

  document.write('<span id="ramd1"></span><br /><span id="ramd2"></span>');
  
  setInterval(function(){ $('#ramd1').text( myRandom(100, 1200) ); }, 100);
  setInterval(function(){ $('#ramd2').text( myRandom2(100, 1200) ); }, 100);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

попробуй так:

```js
$(function() {
 var ramd1, ramd1;
 function myRandom(from, to, who) {
  if ( who == 1 ) {
   ramd1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * (to - from + 1)) + from);
  }
  else {
   ramd2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * (to - from + 1)) + from);
  }
 }

 setInterval( function () {
  myRandom(100, 1200, 1);
  myRandom(100, 1200, 2);
  document.write(ramd1 + "<br />" + ramd2);
 }, 100);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```